# How to create a variable using string concate in python

Tags: python, string, string-concatenation

I want to create a variable as Variable11 and assign its vcalue to 10.

When using 'Variable'+ str(11) = 10  i get a error  stating cant assign to operator

Is there any better way to create a concate string as variable to assign a value.

Comment: You probably should be using a `list` or a dictionary instead.

Comment: Don't dynamically create variables, *use a container* like a list or a dict.

Comment: You can use globals() but that's not ideal. https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/globals/

Comment: If you try and succeed in creating variables dynamically you have solved only first part of your problem. Second part of the problem will be 'how to dynamically access created variables'. As suggested by earlier comments - use proper datastructures built-in into Python.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

`new_var  = old_var +"11"`

Answer (score -1):

Use `exec()`

```py
>>> exec(f'Variable{str(11)} = 10')
>>> Variable11
10
```